# my zend framework application is not reading htaccess file even after enabling url rewrite in apache

Tags: php, zend-framework, apache2

I have built a Zend Framework application. By configuring it to read `routes.ini` file, my application after deployment is not going to any routes but only default route is working. I have total of 4 routes in this application and none of them are working. Apache is showing a *Not Found* error.

I had look at `.htaccess` file it is perfect and in my local it is working fine. I also checked the permissions. It is having read and write rights for `www-data`. I also checked Apache URL rewrite module.

I did this again and tried:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Still same issue.

My apache error log says that file does not exist.
Please tell me where I have gone wrong.

Comment: can you do a test by writing  "deny all" in your .htaccess  and access http://yourhostname.com/ ?? you should see a 403 error..

Comment: It is not giving me 403 error

Comment: ok then your rewrite module isn't working! can you re enable the rewite module? also did you enable the module in httpd.conf?

Comment: I just did this   sudo a2enmod rewrite to enable will wont do

Comment: did you try uncommenting LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in apache's conf?

Comment: -1 for not attempting to provide complete information on the issue at hand.

Comment: I have only given the answer below after getting to to know about the problem so , This is not fair

Comment: And nobody here who has so much of reputation has identified that there is a problem apache vhost directory file , if @RockyFord needed more information what is your problem in asking for what ever you want

Comment: at a minimum I would have expected the full text of the error log to be posted. While your explanation is important, error logs and code often tell the story in finer detail and reveal where your perceptions might be inaccurate.

Comment: " Apache is showing a Not Found error ". Is the phrase here that I have stressed out What more is required for you @RockyFord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching for hours , I could notice that there was a very minor and sensitive mistake in the apache vhost file .

my entry was like this

```
<Directory /var/www/your_project>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

But actually my entry should be as per [mssb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559445/mssb) some what like this

```
<Directory /var/www/your_project>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory
```

Since I am not an experienced webmaster I couldn't noticed one simple thing which is 
AllowOveride option which was set to None

I referred to Core apace documentation today in order find where I was wrong .

The reason for not picking .htaccess file is as follows

> When AllowOveride directive is set to None, then .htaccess files are
>   completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to
>   read .htaccess files in the filesystem.
>
> When this directive is set to All, then any directive which has the
>   .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files.

I personally felt like Posting this entire solution for the problem to help others who may face a similar problem in future

Once again I would like to thank you all for responding to this post

Comment: Thanks for posting such a detailed explanation of how you solved your problem, I wish more people would do that!

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps to mod_rewrite

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

add following codes

```
<Directory /var/www/your_prject_name>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
    # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
    # Commented out for Ubuntu
    #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
 </Directory>
```

then restart the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I already have this setup , and but still the same issue , It is not picking up .htaccess file